# Java Iterate over nested map

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop

Please guide me to iterate over each element  and print

```
        for (Entry<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>>>> zones : zoneOrderedTicketList.entrySet()) {
            for (String string : zones.getValue()) {

            }
        }
```

TicketDetailsDTO object  has name and id as fields

Comment: What are you asking; how to get more than one value in a `foreach`?

Comment: All I can say is "holy crap" `Entry<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>>>>` This isn't addressing the question but you should consider finding a way to simplify that

Comment: You will need to traverse through the key/values of **every inner map**.

Comment: Why are you making deep nesting resolve it to somthing which is efficient

Comment: i want to iterate to  from maps down to list and print list items  please see how could we do this

Comment: `zones.getValue()` will return `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>>>` so, again, as said in my comment before, you will need to traverse through the key/value elements of every inner map in your iterator until you get the elements of your `List`. Note that this is a **very odd** approach and you should avoid it.

Comment: There is no other way to iterate them one by one.

Comment: What you are searching for is a functionality `flatting` a map. I believe there should be solutions for that.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
for (Entry<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>>>> zones : zoneOrderedTicketList.entrySet()) {
         for(Entry<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>>> map2 : zones.getValue().entrySet()){
             for( Entry<String, Map<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>> map3 : map2.getValue().entrySet()){
                 for(Entry<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>> map4: map3.getValue().entrySet()){
                     for(TicketDetailsDTO ticketDetailsDTO : map4.getValue()){
                         // Play with your code here 
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is horrible. There recently seems to be a rather concerning tendency to represent *trees* as nested maps. Trees are not nested maps. Trees are trees. You should **definitely** review this.

However, concerning the general question about iterating over nested maps: The [Stream#flatMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method from Java 8 allows flattening nested structures. A basic sketch of an idiomatic (note the "ma"!) approach for achieving the described goal could roughly look like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>>>> zoneOrderedTicketList =
    new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>>>>();

Stream<Entry<String, List<TicketDetailsDTO>>> stream =
    zoneOrderedTicketList.entrySet().stream().flatMap(
        (e0) -> e0.getValue().entrySet().stream().flatMap(
            (e1) -> e1.getValue().entrySet().stream().flatMap(
                (e2) -> e2.getValue().entrySet().stream())));
stream.forEach((e3) -> {
    List<TicketDetailsDTO> list = e3.getValue();
    System.out.println(list);
});
```

(It should not even be necessary to store the stream in the `stream` variable. But directly calling `forEach` on the resulting stream at least causes the Eclipse type inference to bail out and consider the contained objects as `Object`, and not as `Entry`s)